# CSS Transition making tile position wrong (Angular Material)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Using angularjs I'm displaying some tiles I am filtering using a search input.

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="4" md-cols-lg="6" md-cols-gt-lg="8"
                md-row-height-gt-md="1.2:1" md-row-height="1:1"
                md-gutter="10px" md-gutter-gt-sm="10px">

            <md-grid-tile class="gray" ng-repeat="carto in cartoList | filter : { fullDisplayName: searchInput}">
                <md-button ng-click="changeSVG(carto.fileName)" aria-label="carto.displayName">
                    <img src="style/images/thumbnails/{{carto.fileName}}.png" width="100%" height="100%"></img>
                </md-button>
                <md-grid-tile-footer><h3 align="center">{{carto.displayName}}</h3> </md-grid-tile-footer>
            </md-grid-tile>

        </md-grid-list>
```

This works fine, only the tiles matching the search input are displayed.

But I want to add some animation effect when the display changes.
So with this CSS code :

```
md-grid-tile {
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out 100ms;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out 100ms;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease-out 100ms;
transition: all 500ms ease-out 100ms;
}
```

There is an animation just like I want.

But the positions of the tiles are not changed.

For example if some tiles matching the search are in the middle of the page, after some other tiles.
The other tiles will disappear and the tiles matching the search will stay, but at the same position, they are not moved to the beginning of the page.

Weridly, matching tiles are moved at the proper position only when clearing the search input.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You want it to animate as items leave and enter the list?

Comment: What list ? The list of items being displayed ?
I want to animate whenever the display change, meaning when the number of items matching the filter changes

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the ngAnimate module (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). It lets you set animations for items in an ng-repeat for enter and leave. So when an item matches a filter you can have it animate on enter, and when it doesn't match the filter it will animate the leave

Comment: It looks like angular material have some issues with transitions : https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1559